# Is it possible to create a non-proximity voice chat in Roblox?

Tags: roblox

So just in general, I'm asking if Roblox voice chat service has this feature? I know they have spatial voice, but I want to know if its possible to make the voice chat global? Like the voice chat in League of Legends or Dota 2, I making a game similar to that fashion, and I want to add that kind of feature?

Any info on this topic is actually pretty helpful, I checked the documentation and I'm not sure if they included everything or I just missed some part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible yet. Handling the voice chat is entirely in the hands of Roblox right now, as they put lots of limitations on how developers can handle it.

[This post](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/release-notes-for-498/1497789/5) describes that new programmability may come in the future, but considering the date of the post, it might've been put on the back burner instead of being a priority feature.